# How to get the training metrics in a file?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have trained my own NER model. I would be interested to know if I can retrieve the metrics somewhere in a file after the training. Only as output from the console, they are unfortunately not usable for me.

I used the following command:

```
java -cp /content/stanford-ner-tagger/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier /content/ner-model1.ser.gz -testFile /content/test1.tsv
```

[image: output:]

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the output as a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep all the output at training time by redirecting it to a file, `> asdf.txt` or `> asdf.txt 2>&1`

You can recreate the confusion matrix with

`java edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier your_classifier.ser.gz -testFile your_test_file.txt`

Comment: Is it possible to suppress the output of the entire test file in the console?

Comment: Going off memory, I believe the test file goes to stdout and the statistics to stderr.  So, you can just do `> /dev/null`, or on windows, `> NUL`